# intel AppFamework how to display JSON data

Tags: javascript, android, json, appframework, intel-xdk

im developing app by using intel xdk and i want to show JSON data coming form web page in my page.here is my code..

```
   function LoadJsonDataFunction()
{  
    $.getJSON("json_Data_webpage.php", function(obj) {
$.each(obj.employees, function(key, value){
$("allemployees").append("<li>"+value.fname+"</li>");
    });
 });
}
```

im calling above function in the body tag

```
 <body onload="LoadJsonDataFunction()">
 <ul id="allemployees"> </ul>
```

but this code is not working.

i have found jqm plugin for AppFramework.how can i use it to solve this.

Comment: instead of giving onload call LoadJsonDataFunction(); inside document.ready check it would work...

Comment: tried.but still not working.is there any wrong with my code syntax?

Comment: k if ur using onload the script u declared the LoadJsonDataFunction() is below the body or in the head section...

Comment: its in the head section

Comment: as meier ans is change it  and place the script at the end of body....

Comment: place script at the end of the body tag.but still no luck.

Comment: can u place a fiddle of wat u have done inorder to help u....

Comment: hi allright i have posted a small fiddle which helps how to get json data from url and append to html page...do as same as this will work..http://jsfiddle.net/2xTjf/

Comment: im developing this app using intel xdk.i have tried but intel emulator does not provide required output.

Comment: have u checked the above fiddle and tried ur code in that way...

Comment: yes but not working..here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/kUrv7/

Comment: i am unable to access the url u have given through my sys could'nt help u friend..

Comment: its ok..thnaks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("allemployees")` should probably be `$("#allemployees")`, so it selects the html-element with the id allemployes.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution...call to this function from "deviceIsReady"

```
       <script>
/*Load remort data function*/


function loadRemortData(){
 document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.remote.data",function(event){
        if(event.success==false){
            $('#mytaskslist').append('<li data-divider-theme="a"><center><a  href="#win1" data-transition="pop" data-icon="alert">Error in connection</a></center></li>');
        } else {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(event.response);
            $.each(obj.employees, function(key, value){
                $('#mytaskslist').append(' <li><a href="#"><img src="images/b_add.png" />  <h3>'+value.sub+'</h3><p>'+value.des+'</p> <p>'+value.date+'</p> </a> </li>');
            });
            $('#mytaskslist').listview('refresh');
        }
    }, false); 

    var parameters = new intel.xdk.Device.RemoteDataParameters();
    parameters.url = "url_to_the_page.php";
    intel.xdk.device.getRemoteDataExt(parameters);
}
```